# Why is the instance of an object not from my extended class, but from the original class, in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel

In a Laravel 4.2 project I'm using the  Money (https://github.com/mathiasverraes/money) library by Mathias Verraes. I've included it in the "require" section of the composer.json file like so:

```
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2",
        "mathiasverraes/money": "1.2.1",
```

All is working fine, now I want to override 1 function (named "stringToUnits") in the Money class. What I have done:

1) I've created a file app/lib/Projectname/Extensions/Money.php to hold that function.

```
<?php namespace Projectname\Extensions;

use Money\Money as OriginalMoney;

class Money extends OriginalMoney {

    public static function stringToUnits($string)
    {
        ...my version...            
    }

}
```

2) I'm trying to use the new version of stringToUnits in a service like this:

```
<?php namespace Projectname\Services\Payment;

use Projectname\Extensions\Money as Money;

class EloquentPaymentService implements PaymentServiceInterface {

    private function compareAmountsInAccountsPayable($accountsPayable, array $payment_data) {   

        $amount_to_pay = Money::EUR(Money::stringToUnits($accountsPayable->amount_due_in_document_currency));
        $amount_paid   = Money::EUR(Money::stringToUnits($payment_data['amount_due_in_document_currency']));

        $difference = $amount_paid->subtract($amount_to_pay);

        if( $difference->isNegative() ) {

            return $this->clearAccountsPayableWithNegativeDifference($accountsPayable, $payment_data, $difference);         
        }

    }


    private function clearAccountsPayableWithNegativeDifference($accountsPayable, array $payment_data, Money $difference) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Now the function is doing its thing correctly, but Laravel gives me an error I didn't expect:

```
Argument 3 passed to Projectname\Services\Payment\EloquentPaymentService::clearAccountsPayableWithNegativeDifference() must be an instance of Projectname\Extensions\Money, instance of Money\Money given
```

So I'm puzzled:  Why is the Money object I created an instance of the original \Money\Money and not from my extended class \Projectname\Extensions\Money?
I thought I was telling that to Laravel by stating "use Projectname\Extensions\Money as Money;"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
$amount_paid = Money::EUR(Money::stringToUnits($payment_data['amount_due_in_document_currency']));
```

From what it looks like, the original parent class methods are returning new instances of itself as a result. Your extending class doesn't have a `EUR` method, so it bubbles up to the parent and the parent class returns a `Money\Money` instance.

```
$difference = $amount_paid->subtract($amount_to_pay);
```

`$difference` is no longer acting upon your extending class by that point. It's acting upon the original `Money\Money` instance returned by the `EUR` call. You can confirm this by dumping the results of your `$amount_paid` variable, or using your IDE's built-in debugger and looking at the contents at that particular breakpoint.

The error can be removed by eliminating the typehint on your third argument. If you would prefer to keep it, then you will need to override the parent's `callStatic` method with something like this:

```
namespace Projectname\Extensions;

use Money\Money as OriginalMoney;
use Money\Currency;

class Money extends OriginalMoney {

    public static function stringToUnits($string)
    {
        ...my version...            
    }
    public static function __callStatic($method, $arguments)
    {
        return new Money($arguments[0], new Currency($method));
    }
}
```

The code is untested, so I can't guarantee it will work right out of the gate. But that should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks maiorano84, I think you are on the right track. I can confirm - by dumping - that the $amount_paid variable is acting upon the original Money\Money object. And yes, I can confirm that the error is removed by eliminating the Money typehint. Still: I would like to keep the Money typehint. So I tried your suggestion to override the __callStatic method. Now  $amount_paid is acting upon the extended class (yeah!) but $difference is not. So maybe I should copy the 'subtract' method to the extended class as well, I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Correct, that should work. You can see on [Line 181](https://github.com/mathiasverraes/money/blob/master/lib/Money/Money.php#L181) that a new instance of Money is also being returned there, which I had missed. Overriding that in the extending class should correct your issues for this specific use-case.

Comment: I added a copy of the subtract method from the original Money class to the extended class ("public function subtract(Money $subtrahend)" and Laravel gives me the error: Declaration of Projectname\Extensions\Money::subtract() should be compatible with Money\Money::subtract(Money\Money $subtrahend). Notice that the error message didn't pickup the arguments definition in the extended Class version. Any suggestions what's going on here?

Comment: Hmm.... in your extended class, try typehinting the subtract method with `OriginalMoney`

Comment: That takes care of it. And results in: Call to private method Money\Money::assertSameCurrency() from context 'Projectname\Extensions\Money'.  So..going down this road I will end up copying all methods needed for this use case and adjust them as needed. Maybe there are better solutions, but meanwhile you did answer my original question, thanks!

Comment: Something to look into: The next release of the Money package plans on declaring class Money as final, so extending it in the future will be impossible. With that in mind, you might want to consider refactoring the Extension class as a wrapper around Money, and declare Money as a dependency. That way, the results might be a bit more predictable and you won't need to override each method you plan on leveraging. Hopefully that helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I finally came up with an easy solution. I saw we already had a `class Utils` in the project. I just created my `public static function stringToUnits($string)` in that class and changed my code to calls like  `$amount_paid = Money::EUR(Utils::stringToUnits($paym...)`. No wrapper needed, I don't have to touch the original library and it is a bit future proof, when the declaring final will be in effect. Maybe this helps other readers, and thanks for your help and comments maiorano84!